# Show convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $x$ be a complex number with $|x| = 1$ and such that for some $k ∈ \mathbb{N}$ we have
$x^k=−x$ (for example $x = −1$ or $x = i$). Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}
$
is convergent

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question, Tom.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** Show with a summation by parts that for $x \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|x|=1$,
$$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{x^n}{n} \text{ converges } \Longleftrightarrow x\neq 1$$

Comment: Do you know Abel's summation by parts ?

Comment: No I don't know that, maybe I've forgotten, I'll look it up. All I've done is used the ratio test to show convergence to 0.

Comment: If you apply ratio test to the series $\sum x^n/n$, you will get that the series converges if $|x|<1$, and that it diverges if $|x|>1$. But ratio test cannot help you determine if the series converges or not for the $|x|=1$. That's why you need a more efficient tool to study the series for the $|x|=1$. The good tool is summation by parts (which leads to Dirichlet's test) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Comment: How would I do sum by parts to solve this?

Comment: Actually, summation by parts is used to prove Dirichlet's test. So what you can do is the following : prove Dirichlet's test in the general case with summation by parts (see the Wikipedia page if you have trouble, this is perfectly done here), and then, apply Dirichlet's test with your specific series.

Comment: How would I apply dirichlets test in this case?

Comment: Your series is $\sum x^n \times \left( 1/n \right)$. So the general term is the product of two factors. Try to see which one is monotonic and tends to $0$, and which one gives bounded partial sums.

Comment: Would it be fine to show that the series satisfies condition for dirilech test and then prove it in general case

Comment: What do you mean ? If you want to apply Dirichlet's test, you have to know how to prove it.

Comment: Also does x^n give bounded partial sums? If so what is it?

Comment: Write down the partial sums. It is a geometric series, you have a formula. See when the partial sums are bounded. And try to take initiative, and to figure things by yourself : it will be far more useful for you than if I (or someone else) give you direct complete answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not know summation by parts (also known as Abel's summation):

Putting $A_0=0$, $A_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$, there holds

$$\sum_{k=1}^na_kb_k=\sum_{k=1}^n(A_k-A_{k-1})b_k=\sum_{k=1}^nA_kb_k-
\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^nA_{k-1}b_k}_{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A_kb_{k+1}}=A_nb_n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}A_k(b_k-b_{k+1})\text.$$